# Populate the values set in one controller in retrieving from another controller using getters and setters

Tags: java, spring

I have two different controllers one for fetch and one for submit and one common service class.

Ajax Controller1 :

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/someUrl"})
public Map<String, String> fetchList() {
List<Make> makes = testService.getMakes();

}
```

TestService class code method is below

```
private List<Make> makes ;
```

//getters for makes and **setters** for makes

```
public List<Make> getMakes() {
        try {

            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("input.json");
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(resource.getFile()));
            List<Make> makes  = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create()
                    .fromJson(jsonReader, new TypeToken<Map<Make, List<Model>>>() {
                    }.getType());
            setMakes(makes);**//Here I am setting value**
            return makes;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Ajax Controller 2:
I am injecting

```
@TestService service;
@PostMapping(value = {"/mainURL"})
    public Map<String, String> submitList() {
        service.getMakes()
    }
```

Both these ajax controllers are called on the same page.

> Is it a good practice to do so.Here I am setting value in service from
>   Controller1 and fetching the values in another Controller2.

Comment: why don't you have one controller with two different methods, one for get and other to set

Comment: It’s called in two different  events and scenarios.

Comment: okay but root path is same?

Comment: Yes but how does it matter we have different relative paths after content root

Comment: Okay why are you thinking that you need two different controllers?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

1. AjaxController1
2. Service layer for AjaxController1
3. getMakes()
4. AjaxController2
5. Service layer for AjaxController2
6. Autowire Service of AjaxController1
7. Create function and get the makes list using autowired service1
8. return list.

Comment: Hi Anurag I think this is what I am doing r8.Are you saying for two controller we need to create two separate services?

Comment: Yes! Depending upon the application architecture and no. of modules we create the controllers. And each controller has its own service layer.